# EF Code First not generating database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to follow the simple demo located at the following link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ554735.aspx

I have a breakpoint set at the "db.SaveChanges" method and every time I run the application, another blog name gets added which is expected.

However, I can't find the database anywhere on my local server! I've captured the connectionstring during debugging, and it is defined as the following:

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=MigrationsAutomaticDemo.BlogContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

I'm able to log into my local database using "Bill-pc" as my server name with Windows authentication. I've tried logging on as the above mentioned datasource, but cannot get in. There are no other local servers on my machine except for "Bill-pc".

I **do not** have SQLEXPRESS installed.

I'm using **SQL Server 2014 with Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.**

The database **has to exist somewhere**, because each time I run it, another blog in the list shows up from the console window.

Does anybody know how I can view the "MigrationsAutomaticDemo.BlogContext" database and what server it's on? What am I doing wrong where I can't get into the server to view the database and its table contents?

This has me baffled....

Comment: Never mind... I figured it out.... First of all, I don't know where the first 3 blogs are residing, but when I put in a connectionstring with the "Bill-pc" as the datasource in the app.config file and ran it again, only 1 blog showed up because it was obviously a different datasource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, select View => SQL Server Object Explorer

[image]

You can find the localDb in the SQL Server Object Explorer Window

[image]

Comment: Found it under the (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB server. Thanks a lot for your insight!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using default SQL Server instance, I guess you should change your connection string to `"Data Source=bill-pc;Initial Catalog=MigrationsAutomaticDemo.BlogContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"`

Comment: You are correct... I just figured that one out.... I also assume before the DB is created, you actually have to run it through the "Save" method in order to create the DB, table, record....

Answer (score 1):

Can you find the database if you try to connect using `(localdb)\ProjectsV12` as the server name? I had a similar issue trying to find a local DB and I was able to connect with this. It is case sensitive.

I believe you can find the local DB instances at

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances
```

If you don't have ProjectsV12 there, try to connect to `(localdb)\TheFolderYouDoHave`.

Comment: Got it from the above & below answers. Thanks for your input!